# geopandas on Amazon Linux 2 arm64

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, arm, geopandas

I'm trying to get a python tool install on an Amazon Linux 2 ec2 instance running on arm64. It requires geopandas. This install fails with the message below.

```
pip install geopandas
Collecting geopandas
  Downloading geopandas-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (935 bytes)
Collecting pandas>=0.25.0 (from geopandas)
  Downloading pandas-1.3.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting shapely>=1.6 (from geopandas)
  Downloading shapely-2.0.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl.metadata (7.0 kB)
Collecting fiona>=1.8 (from geopandas)
  Downloading fiona-1.9.5.tar.gz (409 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 409.3/409.3 kB 9.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-install-_c7449ly/fiona_e22cd934b7ad4d2e824ee7831b133267/setup.py:86: DeprecationWarning: The 'warn' function is deprecated, use 'warning' instead
        logging.warn("Failed to get options via gdal-config: %s", str(e))
      WARNING:root:Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config': 'gdal-config'
      CRITICAL:root:A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
SUPPORT_END="2025-06-30"
```

Has anyone got geopandas install working on AL2 on arm64? Thanks.

I've tried installing gdal, however many of the dependencies fail. gdal-config cannot be found. Must I build from source?

Comment: Try this conda install python=3 geopandas

Comment: Was hoping to do this via pip to avoid conda. Getting conda on arm is a whole task itself.

Comment: Are you using Debain Bullsyes or Bookworm?

Comment: One last thing is have you try pip3 install pyproj?

Comment: I believe the amazon linux 2023 ami is fedora, I can give debian os a try, but trying to figure out AL2023.
This worked: pip3 install pyproj 
but still have the same error with fiona in the geopandas install

Comment: pip install .\Fiona-1.8.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: ERROR: Fiona-1.8.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: That all I can gave.